# PHP login page using prepared statements

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I am new to the concept of prepared statement and i am trying to adjust my "user login" function to be a prepared statement. The part i am really struggling with is the fact i have multiple SQL queries in the one function and the biggest hurdle right now is fetching from a prepared statement.

Here is the code i have written for the function so far, i do apologise its a mess and i understand there is parts that shouldn't be in there, i just left everything in.

```
function login_member() {

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecom_db");
    if(isset($_POST['login_button'])) {

        $email = filter_var($_POST['log_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 

        $_SESSION['log_email'] = $email; 
        $password = $_POST['log_password']; 

        $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT email AND password FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=? AND com_code IS NULL");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->execute()) {

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            //result is in row

            }

        }
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                while (($row = $res->fetch_assoc()))
                   $username = $row['username'];


            $closed = $connection->prepare("SELECT email AND password FROM users WHERE email=? AND user_closed=?");
            $closed->bind_param('ss', $email, "yes");
            $closed->execute();
            $closed->bind_result($email, "yes");
            $closed->store_result();
            $closed_res = $closed->get_result();

            if($closed->num_rows == 1) {
                $open = $connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_closed=? WHERE email=?");
                $open->bind_param('ss', "no", $email);
                $open->execute();
                $open->bind_result("no", $email);
                $open->store_result();
            }

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: ../public/member/index.php");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            set_message("Email or password was incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that it looks like a complete mess, i have left all my working outs in there. My main issue here is after my initial statement, i want to be able to fetch the results from the returned row and set the "username" a column in that row to the variable $username.

My original, working code (without prepared statements) is as follows.

My original - without prepared satatements is as follows.

```
function login_new_member() {

    if(isset($_POST['login_button'])) {

        $email = filter_var($_POST['log_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); //sanitize email

        $_SESSION['log_email'] = $email; //Store email into session variable 
        $password = md5($_POST['log_password']); //Get password md5

        $check_database_query = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND com_code IS NULL");
        confirm($check_database_query);
        $check_login_query = mysqli_num_rows($check_database_query);

        if($check_login_query == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_database_query);
            $username = $row['username'];

            $user_closed_query = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND user_closed='yes'");
            confirm($user_closed_query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($user_closed_query) == 1) {
                $reopen_account = query("UPDATE users SET user_closed='no' WHERE email='$email'");
                confirm($reopen_account);
            }

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: ../public/member/indexhold.php?register_new");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            echo "Email or password was incorrect";
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: I'ts hard to tell what is your actual problem. you says your problem is with fetch, but posts actually a lot of code that is irrelevant to fetch and is a complete mess even without prepared statements. you better post your original function that works

Comment: I have edited my post to include my working function.

Comment: what's the purpose of changing user_closed from yes to no?

Comment: If a users account has been closed, throughout the site that users profile and posts will be hidden. If the customer would like to reopen their account they can simply log in and as you can see if the user_closed is set to yes it will change it to no and effectively "reactivate" their account..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. An extra query to get exactly the same row you just requested
2. Unreliable password hashing
3. Inconsistent query handling with strange query()/confirm() pair.
4. A lot of things intermixed here - POST, database internals, everything.

To make it better you have to store passwords after hashing them with `password_hash()` function and also utilize an improved version of query() function. 
So the final code would be like this (it is using my [simple DB wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper) which is based on PDO, but could be implemented using mysqli as well). So the idea is that you do all the prepared statements' related stuff inside the database class, and never touch it inside a user function.

```
function login_new_member($email, $password)
{
    $user = DB::run("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND com_code IS NULL", [$email]);

    // you really should switch to password_hash/password_verify    
    // and make the following line as 
    // if ($user && password_verify($password, $user['pass']))
    // but for now
    if ($user && md5($password) === $user['password']))
    {
        if ($user['user_closed'] == 'yes')
        {
            DB::run("UPDATE users SET user_closed='no' WHERE email=?", [$email]);
        }
        $_SESSION['log_email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
        header("Location: ../public/member/indexhold.php?register_new");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Email or password was incorrect";
    }
}
```

so this function should be called like this

```
if(isset($_POST['login_button'])) {
    login_new_member($_POST['log_email'], $_POST['log_password'])
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your reply, I am sorry for the messiness of my code, The query and confirm functions are simply little helper functions i create at the start of my functions file to save typing out queries every time. (should of explained that)
What you have scripted out there is very tidy and appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: can i just add that i have not used PDO before. 
in the part of this code where you have "$user = DB::run" for me it returns an error message of "Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found" 
I take it DB is the database, would i need to declare this?

Comment: yes. this code serves for the demonstration purpose mostly, to give you an idea

Comment: However you can take that DB class from the link in my answer.

Comment: Yes i am just reading through all of that, it obviously seems like a great tool. It's definitely something i'd like to take full advantage of. The only issue I'm going to have is I will need to rewrite all my code now to accommodate this new method. Like i say i've never used PDO now i get the following error "Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PDO' does not have a method 'connection' in C:\xampp\htdocs\OakleyFinal\resources\config.php on line 49"

sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: Well you don't have to call whatever connection with this class. It connects automatically